# Seeing elements of @guest when logged in

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-8

```
<div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-4 mb-sm-5"> 
    <div class="col-12 h-100 c-bg-offwhite p-0">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 text-center">
                <img class="w-100" src="{{ url('/storage/photo_images/'.$image) }}" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 text-left">
                <p class="p color-black d-block px-4 pt-4 pb-3 mt-0 mb-0">{{$photo->title}}</h3>
            </div>
            @guest
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="px-4 pb-4">
                    <a href="/contact"> 
                        <button class="w-100 btn-primary">Get a quote</button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endguest
        </div>
    </div>
    @auth
    <div class="col-12 p-0 mt-3">
        <a href="/photos/{{$photo->slug}}/edit"> 
            <button class="w-100 btn-primary">Edit</button>
        </a>
    </div>
    @endauth
</div>
```

The code is a photo, with a title and a button for customers to click to contact the company. When an end-user is logged in it turns into an edit button, but sits underneath so not to confuse it with the customer facing button. It should be a case of one button on, one button off.

[auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cC9Lw.png)

[guest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x0Jj.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry for not really understanding your question.
But based on you question and the screenshot you provides it's already do what it shoud do.
@guest will be showing a button with 'Get A Quote' written on it and links to /contact
and @auth will be showing edit button when a user is logged in.